# Append a key to all objects in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add a key to existing array of objects.

```
  session = Session.where(:session_id => events_params[:session_id])

  events_params[:events].each do |event|
      event[:session_id] = session.ids
  end
  puts events_params[:events]
```

Even after assigning this session_id , the event_params[:events] still doesn't contain session_id in any objects as seen from the puts statement. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `event_params` a method that returns a hash? Like from strong params?

Comment: How that `event_params` looks?

Comment: @razvans. def events_params
      params.require(:data).permit(
        :session_id, 
        :user_identifier, 
        :user_email, 
        :auth_token,
        events: [:event_type, :timestamp, data:{}], 
        )
    end

Comment: @razvans Event params are rails permit function , so how to add an extra key to events array before saving to database ?

Comment: Assign `event_params` to a variable and use the variable, not the function.

Comment: After adding this key, I want to do something like Event.insert_all(events_params[:events]) bulk insert.

Comment: Ok, then assign `event_params[:events]` to a variable.

Comment: Cool. That was it . Functions and hashes in this permit looks the same! @razvans

Comment: On a side note event[:session_id] = session.ids has an extremely strong X&Y question smell to it. Why would you want to assign an array of ids in the first place?

Comment: @max. Yes it should be session[0].Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your `params`

```
params.dig(:data, :events)&.each { |event| event[:session_id] = session.ids }
```

After that you can call `events_params`

Don't forget to permit that params

```
def events_params
  params.require(:data).permit(
    :session_id,
    :user_identifier,
    :user_email,
    :auth_token,
    events: [
      :event_type,
      :timestamp,
      :session_id,
      data: {},
    ],
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears like `events_params[:events]` is an empty array. Hence the `.each` cannot point to any elements inside an empty array.

You can use [Array#push()](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#method-i-push) here.

```
event_params[:events] << {:session_id => [1, 2, 3]}

or

event_params[:events].push({:session_id => [1, 2, 3]})
```

Otherwise, if you prefer to use `.each`. You can initialize the array beforehand.

```
event_params[:events] = [{:session_id => nil}]
```